# Plotting standard deviation error bars after grouping data by time and aggregating in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that groups my data by hour (based on a timestamp in my dataframe) and then aggregates the mean and standard deviation. I then plot these on a graph. Currently, the mean is plotted and then the standard deviation appears a separate line on the same graph. (See image below)

[image]

How can I change this so that it appears as error bars instead? Also, if I wanted to add a confidence interval, is there anyway I can do this?

My function that I use to plot this graph below:

```
data_to_plot = df[df.InstanceType == instance]
            final_df = data_to_plot.groupby(data_to_plot.index.hour).aggregate([mean, std])
            final_df.plot(title='Average Price Per Hour of Day for ' + instance + " in the " + region + " region.")
            plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
            plt.ylabel('Spot Price')
            plt.show()
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `errorbars` function. I found the [relevant documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.errorbar.html) by googling "matplotlib errorbars." You can plot confidence intervals of the desired confidence by doubling or tripling the values passed for the `yerr` argument.